# how to import already built database to android app

Tags: android

I am new to android and i have to built an android app which will be a quiz, in this i have to pick random question from a given table everytime.I have already built a database can anybody help me how can i import it to my app.
I am going to use an intent that will call the same activity everytime and each time in an activity an random no. is generated it will check if it is generated earlier or not, if not then it will pick tht question from database.

any other suggestions to implement retrieval of question from database or to implement this app are also welcome.

Comment: Can't you just use file copy to copy the database from your assets to the data location for the app?

Answer (score 1):

As @rwilliams  said you can just copy database from asset to app dir.. u just need to check weather u already copied it or not..

here's how i do it.

just put your database in asset dir.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.aavid.advance.alarm.clock/databases/";
    private String dbName = "world_time.db";
    protected SQLiteDatabase theDatabase; 
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context c, String dbName){
        super(c,dbName, null, 1);
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.context = c;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String path = DB_PATH + dbName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        File f = new File(DB_PATH);
        f.mkdirs();

        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(dbName);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + dbName;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + dbName;
        theDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(theDatabase != null)
            theDatabase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Nasser answered is right, but let me add some annotate :

If you change your DB(add field, change data type,...),

please **DO REMEMBER** to change your DB file name.

If you didn't do this, your APP wouldn't read newest DB file until you uninstall APP and install again.

Answer (score 0):

Users can clear data if they want. So you can not make your database static.
But, If you want to keep your database, you can copy your database to assets folder and when app invoke method `onCreate` of SQLiteHelper, you will copy from assets folder to device.

```
Def.DBNAME = "youdb.sqlite";
```

Here is the sample:

**DBHelper**

```
package vn.mve.db;

import java.util.List;

public interface DBHelper<T> {
    boolean insert(T val);
    boolean update(T val);
    boolean delete(T val);
    List<T> getList(int type);
    T getChild(Object val);
}
```

**DBHandler**

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = DBHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    protected SQLiteDatabase db; 
    private final Context context;  
    private static String PACKAGE_NAME = "";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, Def.DBNAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context; 
        PACKAGE_NAME = this.context.getPackageName();
        Def.FOLDER_DB = "/data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/databases/";
        Log.d(TAG, Def.FOLDER_DB);
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        context.deleteDatabase(Def.DBNAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        // for first database;
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist){
            try {
                copyDataBase("db/" + Def.DBNAME);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabse -> Copy failed!");
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        } else {
            open();
            boolean isExist = false;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'config'", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                isExist = true;
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                isExist = false;
            }
            close();
            Log.d(TAG, isExist + "");
            if (!isExist) {
                this.context.deleteDatabase(Def.DBNAME);
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createDatabase when database has existed");
                    copyDataBase(Def.DBNAME);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabse -> Copy failed!");
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }               
            }
        }
    }   
    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase(String DB) {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            myInput = context.getResources().getAssets().open(DB);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME; 
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDatabase -> File not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDatabase");
        } finally {
              //Close the streams
            try {
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try{
            String myPath = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME;
            File dbFile = new File(myPath); 
            checkDB = dbFile.isFile();
            Log.d(TAG, "checkDatabase: " + String.valueOf(checkDB));
            try {
                File fTmp = new File(Def.FOLDER_DB);
                if (!fTmp.exists()) {
                    fTmp.mkdir();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "checkDatabase" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }catch(SQLiteException e){}
        return checkDB;
    }
    public void open() {
        try {
            String myPath = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
            if(db != null)
                db.close();
            super.close();
    }           
    public SQLiteDatabase getSqlDb() {
        return db;
    }
    public void setSqlDb(SQLiteDatabase sqlDb) {
        this.db = sqlDb;
    }    
}
```

And here:

```
public class MVideo extends DBHandler implements DBHelper<Video> {
    public static final String TAG = MVideo.class.getSimpleName();
    public MVideo(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(Video val) {
        open();
        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ID, val.getId());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.TITLE, val.getTitle());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, val.getThumbnail());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, val.getDescription());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ENGLISH, val.getEnglish());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, val.getVietnamese());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ISVIEW, val.getIsView());
        long result = db.insert(Def.Video.NAME, null, cValues);
        close();        
        return result > 0;
    }

    public boolean insertList(List<Video> list) {
        open();
        db.execSQL("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION");
        for (Video v : list) {
            db.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO " + Def.Video.NAME + " (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\") VALUES" + 
                    " (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")",
                    Def.Video.ID, Def.Video.TITLE, Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, 
                    Def.Video.ENGLISH, Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, Def.Video.ISVIEW,
                    v.getId(), v.getTitle(), v.getThumbnail(), v.getDescription(), v.getEnglish(), v.getVietnamese(), v.getIsView() + ""));
            Log.d(TAG, "insertList -> " + v.toString());
        }
        db.execSQL("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
        close();        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Video val) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Video val) {
        open();
        db.delete(Def.Video.NAME, Def.Video.ID + "=?", new String[]{val.getId()});
        close();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Video> getList(int type) {
        List<Video> list = new ArrayList<Video>();
        open();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Def.Video.GET_ALL, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String ID = c.getString(0);
                String title = c.getString(1);
                String thumbnail = c.getString(2);
                String description = c.getString(3);
                String english = c.getString(4);
                String vietnamese = c.getString(5);
                boolean isView = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(6));
                list.add(new Video(ID, title, thumbnail, description, english, vietnamese, isView));
            }
        }
        close();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Video getChild(Object val) {
        open();
        Cursor c = db.query(Def.Video.NAME, new String[]{
                Def.Video.ID, Def.Video.TITLE, Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, 
                Def.Video.ENGLISH, Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, Def.Video.ISVIEW
        }, Def.Video.ID + "=?", new String[]{val.toString()}, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Video v = new Video(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), 
                c.getString(2), c.getString(3), c.getString(4), 
                c.getString(5), Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(6)));
        close();
        return v;
    } 
}
```